# js looping over a string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, for-of-loop

can anyone, please, tell me why this code does not work?

```
var newbie  = [];

for ( var c of "greetings"){
  var newbie += c;
};
```

I am trying to put characters of "greetings" to an array newbie.

Comment: `var newbie += c;` what do you think this statement is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `+=` to add elements to array. You need to use `Array.prototype.push`

**Note:** Don't use `var` or `let` to declare arrays and objects. Use `const`.

**Reason:** We usually don't reassign the arrays and objects using `=` operator. We generally modify them. So to prevent them from reassigning use `const`. In a special case when you know that you need to change object's value using `=` then you may use `let`

```js
const newbie  = [];

for (let c of "greetings"){
  newbie.push(c);
};
console.log(newbie)
```

You can also use `split()` to convert string into array.

```js
let str = "greetings";
const newbie  = str.split('');
console.log(newbie)
```

Comment: Re: "*Don't use var or let to declare arrays and objects. Use const.*" Why? How is declaring a variable as *const* then immediately modifying it consistent with the concept of a constant?

Comment: @RobG Updated. Please check.

Comment: _How is declaring a variable as const then immediately modifying it consistent with the concept of a constant?_ declaring array or object using `const` makes sense because whole point of declaring something with `const` is that variable won't be reassigned. Array or object declared with `const` doesn't means array or object itself can't be modified

Comment: @Yousaf—constants have been used in mathematics for a very long time for values that will not be changed (i.e. held constant), such as pi and Planck's constant, or factors for converting from say miles to kilometres. Using *const* for objects that **will** change is not consistent with the concept of a constant, devaluing its ability to signify a value that doesn't change. You might as well just use *var* for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you need to use `push()` for adding an element to the last index of the array.

```js
var newbie  = [];
for ( var c of "greetings"){
  newbie.push(c);
};

console.log(newbie);
```

Alternatively, you can use `split()` as a short hand to get that same output:

```js
var text = 'greetings';
var res = text.split('');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop  avoid this statement  `var newbie += c;`  and use `newbie.push(c)`.

Reason : A `var` newbie has already been created as a global variable , you need not create it again in the loop. Use the existing newbie array